# Почему анимация срабатывает нормально первые 2 секунды

Tags: javascript, css

Вот такой вопрос. Попробуйте как только страница загрузится быстро клацнуть на круглешок второй и анимация картинки и фон будет плавная. потом нужно обновлять страницу и опять попробовать будет плавно. остальные случаи потом картинка и фон запаздывают . почему запаздывают не разобрался, в этом вопрос.

```
   https://codepen.io/l-ba-iwanowa/pen/poJZQVN
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>

body,
 .col-1,
 .col-3-4,
  .col-1 p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 15px  50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-name: bbb;
  animation-duration: 5s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

#rcorners1:hover {
 width:600px;
  transform: translate(300px); 
  transition:1s;
}

@keyframes bbb {
 0% {background-color: blue;}
 100% {background-color: red}
}


.asd {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 600px;
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
 position:relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.asd img{
 width: 100%;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 600px;
}

.asd img {
 position:absolute;
 top: 0;
}

.asd img.top {
 /*position:relative;*/
 
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 2s;

}
/*
.asd img.top:hover  {
 opacity: 100;
}*/


.trans {
 opacity: 100  !important;
}


#container {
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.col-1 {
 width:25%;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.col-3-4 {
 width:75%;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.relative {
 position:relative;
}


.black-col {
 position: relative;
 top: -150px;
 background: #474747;
 height: 300px;
 color:white;
 padding: 1rem;
}

.zastup {
 position: relative;
 top:-50px;
 background-color: white;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.slider-bg {
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
 transition: background-color 2s;
}



#container2 {
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}





.slider-nav {
 float:right !important;
}




ul {
 /* Center the content */
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    /* Reset styles */
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {

 /* Rounded border */
        border-radius: 9999px;
        height: 14px;
        width: 14px;

        /* Active dot */
        /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);*/

        /* Inactive dot */
         background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
        /*border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);*/

        /* OPTIONAL: Spacing between dots */
        margin: 0 12px;
        transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
}

.nav-active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  transform: scale(1.5);

}

.clear {
 clear:both;
 zoom: 1;
}



.col-1-3 {
 position: relative;
 width: 33%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 1rem;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

button.abc {
 border: 0;
 background-color: #e86d10;
 padding: 1rem 2rem;
border-radius: 25px;
font-size: inherit;
color: #fff;

}


.price {
 font-size:1.5rem;
 position: relative;
 top:-20px;
}

.description {
 position: relative;
 top:-40px;
word-break: break-all;
white-space: pre-wrap;
font-size: 1.2rem;
 
 }

.p1rem {
 padding: 1rem;
}

.orange {
 color: #e86d10;
}

.apply-font {
 font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;

}


.bg-black {
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}


.bg-blue {
 background-color: rgb(34, 73, 200);
}


 </style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="container">


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur illum ab corrupti impedit culpa provident nemo numquam? Magnam, rerum, magni. Autem quisquam deserunt a est iste iure odit laudantium, dolores.</p>

</div>

<div class="slider-bg ">
<div class="asd">

 <!-- <img  src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tAp9BKosZXs/maxresdefault.jpg" alt=""> -->
 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xCGxXuy.jpg" alt="">
 <img  class="top" src="https://i.imgur.com/D1tDvcG.jpg" alt="">
 <img  class="top" src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/gBv91a9YqyhIxGsxc26x5TORV_8=/0x0:1296x730/1200x800/filters:focal(669x161:875x367)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/66274455/horsegirl.0.jpg" alt="">
 <img  class="top" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-73o9cfxSC7Q/XQMxoVjfdMI/AAAAAAAAUkM/RSi0lSlsQoAfhMHLR-3U8Sfk_PpvZuziQCLcBGAs/s1600/copertina.jpg" alt="">



</div></div>

<div id="container2" style="position: relative;top:-60px; ">
 <ul class="slider-nav">
   <li data-id='0' class="nav-active"></li>
   <li data-id='1'></li>
   <li data-id='2'></li>
   <li data-id='3'></li>
   <li data-id='4'></li>
  </ul></div><div class="clear"></div>

<div id="container2">
 <div class="col-1 black-col">asd</div><!-- 
  --><div class="col-3-4 zastup">







<!-- <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.1.0/anime.min.js'></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log(111);
// document.querySelector('#btn-click').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
//  document.querySelector('.top').classList.toggle("trans");
//  console.log(document.querySelector('.top').classList);
// });


let p = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-bg img');
let pp = Array.from(p);
console.log(pp);

function changeBgColor (){


 if (i == 0 ) {

  document.querySelector('.slider-bg').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
 }
  if (i == 1 ) {
   document.querySelector('.slider-bg').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(34, 73, 200)';
 }
  if (i == 2 ) {document.querySelector('.slider-bg').style.backgroundColor = 'red';}
  if (i == 3 ) {document.querySelector('.slider-bg').style.backgroundColor = 'green';}

}

let i = 1;
function asd(arguments) {
 setTimeout(()=>{
 // b = arrayImages[i];
 // document.querySelector('#slider-hero img').src = b;

  let z = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  let zz = Array.from(z);
  zz.forEach((item)=>{item.classList.remove('nav-active')});
  // console.log(el);
  zz[i].classList.add('nav-active');

  

 b = pp[i];
 pp.forEach((val)=>{
  val.classList.remove('trans');
  
 });
 b.classList.add('top');
 b.classList.add('trans');
 changeBgColor();
 i++;
 if (i ==4) {
  i =0;
 }

 console.log(b);
 asd();
},4000);
}
asd();

document.querySelector('.slider-nav').addEventListener('click',(el)=>{
 if (el.target.tagName === 'LI') {
  let z = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  let zz = Array.from(z);
  console.log(el.target.dataset.id);
   b = pp[el.target.dataset.id];
   pp.forEach((val)=>{
    val.classList.remove('trans');
    
   });
   b.classList.add('top');
   b.classList.add('trans'); 


  zz.forEach((item)=>{item.classList.remove('nav-active');});
   
  el.target.classList.add('nav-active');

  i = el.target.dataset.id;
  changeBgColor();
 }

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Там каждые 2 секунды фейд ин фейдаут картинки меняются. и фон каждые 2 секунды цвет меняется.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Неа. нет, не получается.

Comment: Поясните чуть подробнее, что не корректно работает? Попробовал запустить у себя - потыкать, так и не понял, в чём именно Вы видите проблему. Решить то не проблема )

Comment: крч первая картинка черный фон и сама черная. вторая картинка тоже самое только синее и должно плавно переходить. а оно переходит вначале цвет потом картинку грузит и это ужасно выглядит. А должно плавно переходить весь цвет вместе то есть черное в синее и тдитп а не по очереди хотя там не сильно видно но заметно!!!!!! квадртные рамки картинки а их не должно быть если бы одновременный переход был. Спасиб

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Анимация срабатывает нормально только первый раз потому-что у слайдера не уходит время на то , что бы  убрать прошлый цвет так как он задан в css изначально, остальные цвета берутся из js, отсюда и происходит рассинхрон после 1 раза